# How to "dangerously" set plain text of JSX in React.js?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, jsx

As we know from the [documentation of React](https://facebook.github.io/react/tips/dangerously-set-inner-html.html), we can dangerously set custom HTML in the JSX component like this:

```
<div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: '<b>Hello</b>, <i>World</i>'}} />
```

The question is that are we able to set *plain text JSX* in other JSX component like this:

```
import { Button } from 'react-bootstrap'
...
<div dangerouslySetJSX={{__jsx: '<Button>Hello</Button>'}} />
```

or some else way.

Comment: My uneducated guess would be "no", because the "dangerouslySetInnerHTML" doesn't process the text but just assigns it to the `innerHTML` property. The JSX processing (e.g. conversion to JS with object creation calls) occurs not on runtime.

Comment: What are you trying to do? you could just save the jsx to a variable, yknow?

Comment: @azium I'm trying to use [react-translate-component](https://github.com/martinandert/react-translate-component) package which allows you to localize web application with the "interpolations". The thing is that by this package you can translate plain text and plain text HTML (by *unsafe* way), but in this case you unable to translate components in "the middle of the HTML" and I forced to split JSX to small parts like `HTML` + JSX(`HTML`) + `HTML`.
Am I clear ?